# multiple row update on related table

Tags: mysql, triggers

I would like to update multiple rows of column 'student_total' in Table 'Teacher' when a student is deleted, using triggers/procedures
Updating multiple rows in related tables, many-to-many realtionships
'n' teachers can have 'm' students

1. is it possible at all ? because its not possible to store a
   result set (learnt from your site)
2. in Mysql, Postgress etc?

Thanks in Adv

Ritin

---------------   SQL

```
CREATE TABLE `Teacher` (
  `id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `student_total` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
CREATE TABLE `Student` (
  `id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `Teacher_has_Student` (
  `teacher_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `student_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`teacher_id`,`student_id`),
  KEY `fk_Teacher_has_Student_teacher` (`teacher_id`),
  KEY `fk_breeder_has_breed_student` (`student_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Teacher_has_Student_teacher` FOREIGN KEY (`teacher_id`) REFERENCES `Teacher` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_breeder_has_breed_student` FOREIGN KEY (`student_id`) REFERENCES `Student` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

---

i have triggers for INSERT/DELETE/UPDATE 
ex: 
---------------------- SQL

```
CREATE TRIGGER teacher__student_insert AFTER INSERT ON Teacher_has_Student 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
UPDATE Teacher SET student_total = student_total + 1 WHERE id = NEW.teacher_id;
END;
```

---

The trigger below updates just 1 row, whereas the aim is to update all the rows.

---

```
DELIMITER |
CREATE TRIGGER my_student__delete AFTER DELETE ON Student 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
set @std_id = old.id;
UPDATE teacher SET student_total = student_total - 1 
WHERE id = @std_id;
END
|
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your 2nd trigger doesn't make sense. On a delete of a student you take his `id` and decrease the `student_total` of the teacher, which has accidentally the same `id` as the as the studend.

Your definition plus the first trigger should already do the job. If you delete a student his relations are deleted from `Teacher_has_Student` by the `CASCADE` and on this `DELETE` your triggers **should** be fired to decrease the `student_total` of the affected teachers. Anyway a short Google research shows, that MySQL apparently doesn't fire triggers on a cascaded delete:

http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=13102

**Possible Workarounds**

You could try to fix your 2nd trigger to do the job manually:

```
DELIMITER |
CREATE TRIGGER my_student__delete AFTER DELETE ON Student 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    SET @std_id = old.`id`;
    UPDATE
        `Teacher` AS T
        INNER JOIN `Teacher_has_Student` AS TS ON T.`id`=TS.`teacher_id`
    SET `student_total` = `student_total` - 1 
    WHERE ST.`student_id` = @std_id;
END
|
```

But this will not work, if the `CASCADE` on the `FOREIGN KEY` is executed before your trigger.

Maybe a more reliable workaround is to drop the `FOREIGN KEY` definitions and to create triggers on `Teacher` and `Student` to cascade the deletes and updates to `Teacher_has_Student`.

**Normalize it**

With the workarounds you have to keep a lot of different scenarios in mind to keep `student_total` valid. If it‘s not absolutely necessary to store `student_total` directly at the Teachers-Table, I suggest strongly not to do it.

The information is absolutely redundant. Keep your constraints and cascades, but drop the `student_total` column and delete all triggers. Then use a JOIN to get your student numbers:

```
SELECT
    T.`id`, T.`name`, COUNT(*) AS student_total
FROM `Teacher` AS T
    INNER JOIN `Teacher_has_Student` AS TS ON T.`id`=TS.`teacher_id`
GROUP BY T.`id`
```

Comment: Thanks for the Input.. wanted a second opinion, 
your explanation makes perfect sense, 
Salute

Comment: I found this article, wanted to share
http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/A_Brief_Real-world_Trigger_Example
my web-host doesnt support triggers, so will have to stick to constraints.
@Dervo Thanks again :)